# Knockout JS - update viewModel with AJAX Call

Tags: ajax, mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

there are some similar questions but didn't help me to solve my issue. I can't update my results on page / view  after updating my viewModel with AJAX. I am getting valid AJAX response that updates the view if I reload the page, but not when I click btnAdvancedSearch

I have simple HTML:

```
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdvancedSearch" data-bind="click: refresh" />
    </div>

    <div id="resultslist1" data-bind="template: { name: 'rest-template', foreach: restaurants }">
    </div>
```

And I bind in on document load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     ko.applyBindings(new RestaurantsListViewModel());
});
```

My viewModel is like this, and in it I call refresh that is bound with button

```
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
function RestaurantsListViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.restaurants = ko.observableArray([]);

    var mappedRests = $.map($.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('searchResults')), function (item) { return new Restaurant(item) });
    self.restaurants = mappedRests;

    self.refresh = function () {
    updateRestaurantsList(); //Method executes AJAX and saves result to session.
    var mappedRests2 = $.map($.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('searchResults')), function (item) { return new Restaurant(item) });
    self.restaurants= mappedRests2;
}
```

}

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: first one should be `self.restaurants(mappedRests);`. second one is an ajax, which is asynchronous, you need to put code `var mappedRests2 = $map(...); self.restaurants(mappedRests2);` inside the `success` callback of the ajax.

Comment: When my AJAX is finished, results are saved in sessionStorage (it must be like that) And then I am filling self.restaurants from sessionStorage. Could that be a problem? My console.log shows that values are retrieved

Comment: the way you write it, `that two lines` are executed immediately (before ajax received data from server), ajax will be finished in future, `updateRestaurantsList()` doesn't wait for ajax to finish. If this sounds unfamiliar, please read some basic tutorial on ajax.

Comment: I know what you are saying, and will try direct ajax call from here and bind on success.

But for test, I've put console.log before last line and it prints good, valid and updated object that doesn't render on page.

Comment: Are you using `async:false` option in ajax call? (not recommended by jQuery doc) If you do, `self.restaurants(mappedRests2);` should work.

Comment: I am using regular AJAX call with jquery. no async:false or etc..

Just rewrote my viewModel to do everything on call.success, but still nothing on click, only on page reload i see results

Comment: could you post full current js code?

Comment: I need one reuptation point so I can answer my own question, and comments don't allow so many charachters. Don't know how to do that :) :S

Comment: +1. now you should have enough points to post answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
updateRestaurantsList(); //Method executes AJAX and saves result to session.
```

The comment after the above line indicates that this method is making an asynchronous call. Therefore, it is likely that the line after it is executing before sessionStorage has been populated. Maybe consider having `updateRestaurantsList` return a promise. Then you could update your code to something like this:

```
updateRestaurantsList().then(function() {
    var mappedRests2 = $.map($.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('searchResults')), function (item) { return new Restaurant(item) });
    self.restaurants= mappedRests2;
});
```

This way the call to populate your `mappedRests2` variable won't happen until after your `updateRestaurantsList` method has completed.

### Edit 1

Be sure to never assign values to an observable using an equal sign.

```
// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
 function RestaurantsListViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.restaurants = ko.observableArray([]);

     var mappedRests = $.map($.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('searchResults')),     function (item) { return new Restaurant(item) });
      self.restaurants(mappedRests);

      self.refresh = function () {

    var latitude = sessionStorage.getItem('latitude');
    var longitude = sessionStorage.getItem('longitude');
    var query = '{"Accepts_Reservations":"' + $('#chkReservation').is(":checked") + '","Accepts_Cards":' + $('#chkAcceptsCards').is(":checked") + '"}';
    var searchResults = getRestaurantsAdvancedSearchAJAX(query, latitude, longitude, 40);

    searchResults.success(function (data) {
        var information = data.d;

        var mappedRests2 = $.map($.parseJSON(information), function (item) { return new Restaurant(item) });

        self.restaurants(mappedRests2);
    });

  };
};
```

Comment: I am doing that inside of my AJAX method. And before line self.restaurants= mappedRests2; I console.log the response and it is good but my view is not updated

Answer (score 1):

I have tried waiting for AJAX to finish like this:

```
 // Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
 function RestaurantsListViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.restaurants = ko.observableArray([]);

     var mappedRests = $.map($.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('searchResults')),     function (item) { return new Restaurant(item) });
      self.restaurants = mappedRests;

      self.refresh = function () {

    var latitude = sessionStorage.getItem('latitude');
    var longitude = sessionStorage.getItem('longitude');
    var query = '{"Accepts_Reservations":"' + $('#chkReservation').is(":checked") + '","Accepts_Cards":' + $('#chkAcceptsCards').is(":checked") + '"}';
    var searchResults = getRestaurantsAdvancedSearchAJAX(query, latitude, longitude, 40);

    searchResults.success(function (data) {
        var information = data.d;

        var mappedRests2 = $.map($.parseJSON(information), function (item) { return new Restaurant(item) });

        self.restaurants = mappedRests2;
    });

  };
};
```

### Edit 1

Once you have declared your observable like so:

```
self.restaurants = ko.observableArray([]);
```

When you want to update `restaurants` you cannot do this:

```
self.restaurants = mappedRests2;
```

Instead, you need to do this:

```
self.restaurants(mappedRests2);
```

Comment: lol. I meant to edit my own answer, but I'll leave it here just the same.

Comment: :)

Tried self.restaurants(mappedRests2); but getting TypeError: self.restaurants is not a function.

Your answer makes sense but what is this error about?

Comment: knockout.js requires non-null values for all fields that are to be auto mapped.

How to correct that in this case?

Comment: There appears to be a couple areas in your code where you are assigning a value to `self.restaurants` using an equals sign -- once with `mappedRests` and once with `mappedRests2`. Are you sure you have updated your code in both places?

Comment: Oh that is it. I followed some bad examples of Knockout JS implementation, obviously.

You can copy/paste my code with solution so I can give you a vote